# SQL varchar variable inserts question mark

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've a database value that when inserted into a SQL variable, shows with question mark at the end !!  can't find a reason?!

```
declare @A varchar(50) = 'R2300529‏'  
select @A
```

Results:  `R2300529?`

any explanation? i'm using `SQL server 2012`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is unrecognizable character in your string:

[image]

that is giving that `?`. Delete the value and retype, see my screenshot above.

Comment: HTML source shows: `declare @A varchar(50) = 'R2300529&rlm;'`

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you copy/pasted this value from somewhere.  Either that, or you're making some brain teaser here.  But copy/pasting the exact script you supplied reveals an additional character: 0x3F, which is a `?` based on the Hex to ASCII conversion.

I'd recommend just retyping your script and not copy/pasting.

Answer (score 4):

It is actually Right-to-left-mark at the end of your string. Inspect this very page with developer tools and look at your string, you will see that.